# What is a best practice for handling paths in Python modules?

Tags: python, pandas, module, path, sys

I have the following folder structure in Linux:

```
Model
|
|-----Shared_Modules (contains shared.py, a module full of shared functions)
|
|-----Segment_Sales (contains main.py, run the model from this file)
            |
            -----------data (contains data.csv)
```

main.py in the `segment_sales` folder calls functions from the shared_modules folder.  Everytime I call a function, I have to pass a path to it. I feel like I am passing a lot of paths into every single function, and I just don't know this is the right way.  Am I missing a way to this more simply?

Right now a simple example of my main.py file is:

```
working_dir=os.getcwd()
shared_path = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
sys.path.append(os.path.join(shared_path, "Shared_modules/"))
import shared_modules as sm
```

The first 3 lines add the path where shared_modules is located to `sys` so I can have access to the shared_modules.py module.

Here is an example of a function I'd pull in shared_modules.

```
def get_input_data(input_path, model_name):
    config = pd.read_excel('data/Sales_and_Input_Files/model_input_file.xlsx', sheet_name='config', engine='openpyxl')
    print(input_path)
    return config
```

This simple function is an example of how I'm having to pass an input path to `get_input_data` when I just want it to use the `shared_path` above. When I try to just run main and call something from `shared_module.py`, it can't find the path unless I pass it directly to the function, and this occurs with every function in `Shared Modules`.  Thanks in advance for advice.

Edit: I realize I oversimplified my sample function and didn't use the input path for any reason. I added a simple print statement to demonstrate that it might be used.

Comment: you shouldn't be doing this: `sys.path.append(os.path.join(shared_path, "Shared_modules/"))`

Comment: I usually do two things: (1) create a package for your repo to allow for proper includes of modules (e.g., follow [this](https://goodresearch.dev/setup.html#create-a-pip-installable-package-recommended)), (2) create a `config.py` file in your root where you define all paths, e.g., `paths = dict(data = pathlib.Path('C:\data'))`, import the module and then locate the file via `config.paths['data']/'file.xlsx'`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga well then what should I be doing?  That's why I asked for some advice in the first place.

Comment: @Jhonny This is a very helpful link.  Let me read through it and follow the advice provided and see if that improves it.  One problem is that I have to pass it to others (without Docker when I'd prefer to use it) so I have to be careful with absolute references.